# Bootstrap navbar wont collapse

Tags: javascript, html, navbar, nav

My bootstrap navbar that i got from the bootstrap jumbotron example won't collapse. If it is that i dont have the right javascript, css or Jquery links pls send me the right ones. I am kinda new to the navbar thing so i really need some help. Thank you! 
 Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Static top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you mean the toggle button doesn't work, or it doesn't collapse into the mobile version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work properly for me. That just indicates you're missing some JavaScript files. To be more precisely, you are missing Bootstrap and jQuery JS files. Inside your `<body>`, just add both files.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Keep in mind to include jQuery first, otherwise Bootstrap won't work (Bootstrap simply requires jQuery, that's all).

[Here's](https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/yVyYQE) your code, working. I've just copied your markup and added Bootstrap + jQuery.

**EDIT**

I didn't notice you've been using the wront `data-target`. Thanks to @Asifuzzaman Redoy. Just change your `data-target` to the following:

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse"
```

I've updated my fiddle accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped

Answer (score 1):

hey Just Change Your `data-target=".nav-collapse"`  to  `data-target=".navbar-collapse"`

it will work you are not targeting the  right class for collapse

check the below fiddle

[Navbar Collapse Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/DTcHh/26793/)

and you must add the cdn reference

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your toggle data-toggle attribute to .navbar-collapse or #navbar.
Like this.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
```

You are not targeting correct class or id of element through your toggle button.